# Example of hermitian semidefinite positive

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone show me an example of a $3\times 3$ hermitian semidefinite positive matrix? (I mean not only symmetric, but hermitian, with complex coefficients)

There is a lot of work on hermitian semidefinite positive matrices, but it seems that people talk about them and don't take the time to exhibit examples.

Comment: All such matrices are unitarily equivalent to diagonal matrices with real non-negative entries.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a Hermitian matrix will be positive definite if and only if it has positive eigenvalues.  A good "recipe" to quickly build a positive definite matrix is to select diagonal elements that are sufficiently big, since selecting large positive diagonal entries will guarantee positive eigenvalues (positive, since the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are necessarily real).  An example of a more precise (and useful) description of this phenomenon is given by the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

So with that being said: without computing eigenvalues explicitly, I can guarantee that the Hermitian matrix
$$
\pmatrix{100 & 1 - 2i & 3 + 5i\\
1 + 2i & 100 & -9 + i\\
3 - 5i & -9 - i & 100}
$$
is positive definite.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you for the recipe. I wouldn't have thought using the Gershgorin theorem, but now, it's obvious : if the $R_i$ are enough small and the $a_{ii}$ enough large, the corresponding disk is necessarily included in $\{x>0,y>0\}$. Bright!

Comment: Oops, maybe I got too excited... Sorry, I have to investigate further the link with Gershgorin.

Comment: @Andrew you seem to have the right idea.  And again, because the matrix is Hermitian, the eigenvalues are necessarily real.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: The identity matrix is Hermitian and psd.